# Mongoose find with regex is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm try make a select in `MongoDB` with `Mongoose` like something this:

`SQL
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE NAME LIKE '%Sorv%';`

So, I has a `Product` model:

```
mongoose.model('Products'
    , new mongoose.Schema({
            name: {type: String, default: ''},
            price: {type: Number, default: 0},
            prices: [Number]
        })
    , 'products');
```

If I'm try get all register in `Product` model, it will return correct:

```
Product.find()
        .then(function (result)
        {
            var names = result.map(function (item)
            {
                return item.name;
            });
            // return ["Sorvete", "Sorvete Morango", "Sorvete Morango", "Sorvete", "Sorvete"]
            console.log(names);
        });
```

Why when I make a find with `Regex`, according to `Mongoose` document, it return a empty array?

```
Product.find({name: /Sorv/})
        .then(function (result)
        {
            // return a empty array: []
            console.log(result);
        });
```

---

If I set `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and execute fallowing code:

```
Product.find({ name: new RegExp('sorv', 'i') })
.then(function(r){
    console.log(r);
})
```

This return for me fallowing error:

```
[0;36mMongoose:[0m products.find({ name: [32m'/sorv/i'[39m }) { fields: [90mundefined[39m }
```

But if I execute query in mongo command, it return correct result

```
//Return correct results
db.products.find({name: /sorv/i})
```

Mongoose version I using is:

```
console.log(mongoose.version);
4.2.5
```

Comment: What if you'd take this approach: `Product.find({ name: new RegExp('sorv', 'i') })` - does it work? (Ignore Case however means no indexes can be used and you will result in collection scan)

Comment: `Product.find({ name: new RegExp('sorv', 'i') })` is return for me a empty array too

Comment: What if you try the same find command in `mongo` command line? `db.products.find({name:/sorv/i})` - get anything? Also, what Mongoose version you have? Depending on version you may need to do find().exec().then() instead of find().then()

Comment: Can you set debug to true via `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and add the output to your question?

Comment: @jpaljasma If I execute query by command line, is return results

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, managed to solve it like below (as described in [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1403))

```
Product.find({ name: { $regex: 'sorv', $options: 'i'}})
```